# GUI Catkin Qt5 Cmake

Tags: ros, catkin, cmake, qt5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey folks,

I don't really know where to start with my ROS-GUI implementation.
I'm on Groovy and trying to visualize some Messages. I also have a little bit experience with Qt widgets, but don't know how to modify my project for ROS. The roscreate-qt-pkg promt seems not to be known by ROS on my system. Do you maybe know a good reference, from where to start, or have a good code example?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63445/gui-catkin-qt5-cmake/) by [gbd](https://answers.ros.org/users/4969/gbd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On groovy you'll want to use catkin instead of rosbuild.  Perhaps you were following a guide based on fuerte or earlier

Check out this tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_create/Tutorials/Qt%20App%20Templates

---

Originally posted by [adobke](https://answers.ros.org/users/3920/adobke/) with karma: 71 on 2013-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gbd](https://answers.ros.org/users/4969/gbd/) on 2013-05-25**:
Thank you for that answer. I used both promts and both told me that the command is unknown. I have groovy fully installed - all my system variables work properly. I can run all other catkin prompts like creating normal pkg, but when I use catkin[TAB] it even doesn't offer catkin_create_qt_pkg

**Comment by [adobke](https://answers.ros.org/users/3920/adobke/) on 2013-05-25**:
Hmm.  It looks like the source (https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros) doesn't match up to whats actually being installed when ros-groovy-qt-ros is installed.  Perhaps you could manually install that package and try again.

**Comment by [adobke](https://answers.ros.org/users/3920/adobke/) on 2013-05-25**:
You could also grab the template files from https://github.com/stonier/qt_ros/tree/groovy-devel/qt_create/src/qt_create/templates/qt-ros